# Invalid key for O&O Defrag 11 Pro

Tags: performance

It always happens to me. [O&O Software](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/O&O_Software) gave me a license for [O&O Defrag 11 Pro](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/O&O_Defrag), but then the license is invalid.

What do I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Contact O&O support? I'd guess you're already registered.

http://www.oo-software.com/home/en/support/index.html

Of course, if they repeatedly give you an invalid license key then I'd probably ask for a refund and try and find a different product.